# Video screen orientation not changing

Tags: android, android-video-player, landscape-portrait

I design an media player which simply use surface view to render screen and MediaController to control state of video. It support both landscape/portrait mode. I checked it with Nexus-4 and it working fine but same not working on HTC 1 and galaxy.

Some of [forum](http://androidforums.com/htc-evo-4g-lte/594501-problems-when-recording-watching-video-in-landscape-mode.html) suggested to checked with G-Sensor setting. Any idea/suggestion how can overcome  to this issue?

Comment: post code for reference.

Comment: it's simple Surface view with Media Controller...nothing more then that.

Comment: ok, so you are not fixing orientation from your application(programmatically) or else in device settings .. right??

Comment: I maintain config attribute in manifest with "keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" that's it..no fix orientation...n thing is youtube app is working in both mode..so don't think so it is related with g-sensor setting.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the `android:configChanges= "keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` which means now your application need to handle orientation changes. In this case `onConfigurationChanged` method will be always called whenever orientation changes.

So here inside this method you can do what ever you want to do with your video view.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // landscape
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        // portrait
    }
}
```

Comment: ok might be...but same set of code is working for other devices...why is that so?...any idea?

Comment: I think with different android version behavior is changing. go through this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Hi Daud...thanks for ur reply..it help me to check other flow feature of app.